# Has Facebook's FBML redirect tag stopped working?

Tags: facebook, fbml, facebook-fbml

I am trying to use FBML to redirect a user to the Wall after they click the "Like" button. I understand that FBML is the older way to do this. It does not seem to be working at all though. I am using the standard tag:
    
Any ideas?

Comment: Well, Facebook will be [deprecating FBML](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/), maybe this is the reason? Also keep an eye on their [Live Status](http://developers.facebook.com/live_status)

Answer (score 0):

I got this working  so what is your actual problem??Are you using the same tag??I am using FBML application.